# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arguments, geopoints

I have a UITableViewCell and  when I'm running the code below,the codes that were running suddenly gave 3 error. I wrote the problem lines on the code but How can I solve this problem?

UITableViewCell:
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocation
import SDWebImage

```
class anasayfaCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var kullaniciAdiLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yorumLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var kullaniciImagelabel: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var yardimButonLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var anasayfaHarita: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var documentIdLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    yardimButonLabel.text = "Yardım Bekliyor..."
    
    anasayfaHarita.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    anasayfaHarita.layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 15
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    anasayfaHarita.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    anasayfaHarita.isScrollEnabled = false
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

@IBAction func yardimEdildiSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn == true){
     let firestoreDB = Firestore.firestore()
        if let trueOrFalse = Bool(yardimButonLabel.text!) {
            let ValueStore = ["helped" : true ] as [String : Any]
            
            firestoreDB.collection("posts").document(documentIdLabel.text!).setData(ValueStore, merge: true)
        }
        
        
    }
    
}

func prepare(with post: Post) {
    kullaniciAdiLabel.text = post.ownerEmail
    yorumLabel.text = post.comment
    yardimButonLabel.text = String(post.helped)
    yardimButonLabel.text = String(post.id)
    
    
    
    if let imageURL = URL(string: post.imageURL) {
        kullaniciImagelabel.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
    }
    
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(geoPoint: post.location).   **[Argument passed to call that takes no arguments]**
    annotation.title = "Yardım Noktası"
    annotation.subtitle = "Helpet"
    
    anasayfaHarita.addAnnotation(annotation)
    
    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05,longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(geoPoint: post.location), span: span)    **[Argument passed to call that takes no arguments]**
    
    anasayfaHarita.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Let's check the available methods of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d Is there a `init(geoPoint:)`? No. Do you have somewhere in your code such method? (Third party library, you own code, etc.) Else, if you remove that code and try to rewrite it letter by letter, what does tell you the autocompletions of XCode ? Any methods looking alike?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` using a non-existent initializer. Therefore, you can either create this custom initializer or convert the `GeoPoint` into a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in some other way.

To fix your problem outright, just create the initializer:

```
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseFirestore

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    init(geoPoint: GeoPoint) {
        self.init(latitude: geoPoint.latitude, longitude: geoPoint.longitude)
    }
}
```

Another way to go about this is to extend `GeoPoint` to give you a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` whenever you need it:

```
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseFirestore

extension GeoPoint {
    var coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

And to use it just access this property from a `GeoPoint` whenever you need a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = post.location.coordinate2D
```